# Test Class only creating 1 case and email object

Tags: unit-test, failing-tests

I attempted to break up the class based on the different scenarios that might come up, but now I'm only getting 1 case and 1 email message as it's not taking the queried user Id's.

```
@isTest
public class TestMasterCaseTrigger {

    public static final String HELPEMAIL = 'help@company.com';
    public static User SystemUser = [SELECT Id, Name FROM User WHERE Name = 'System' LIMIT 1];
    public static User nonSystemUser = [SELECT Id, Name FROM User WHERE Name = 'Joe Schmoe' LIMIT 1];
    public static User nonSystemUser2 = [SELECT Id, Name FROM User WHERE Name = 'Jack Schmoe' LIMIT 1];

    static testMethod void testEmailOnClosedCaseSystemUser() {              
        createContact('testFirstName', 'testLastName', HELPEMAIL);

        createCase('System User Test', 'New', SystemUser.Id);       

        Case systemCase = [SELECT Id, Status, OwnerId FROM Case WHERE OwnerId=:SystemUser.Id LIMIT 1];
        createEmailMessage('systemUser@company.com', systemCase.Id, 'System User', 'System User Body', HELPEMAIL);
        System.debug('Status of systemCase before update: ' + systemCase.Status);
        System.debug('systemCase: '+ systemCase.Id);        
        systemCase.Status = 'Closed';

        update systemCase;
        Case systemCaseAfterUpdate = [SELECT Id, Status, OwnerId FROM Case WHERE OwnerId=:SystemUser.Id LIMIT 1];
        System.debug('Emails sent on SystemCase Closed: '+ Limits.getEmailInvocations());
        System.debug('Status of systemCase after update: ' + systemCaseAfterUpdate.Status);
        System.assert( Limits.getEmailInvocations()==1,'System should not send emails');
    }
    static testMethod void testEmailOnClosedCaseNonSystemUser(){
        createContact('testFirstName', 'testLastName', HELPEMAIL);
        createCase('Non System User test', 'New', nonSystemUser2.Id);

        Case nonSystemCase = [SELECT Id, Status, OwnerId FROM Case WHERE OwnerId=:nonSystemUser2.Id AND Status != 'Closed' LIMIT 1];
        createEmailMessage('nonSystemUser@company.com', nonSystemCase.Id, 'nonSystem Subject', 'nonSystem Body', HELPEMAIL);
        System.debug('Status of nonSystemCase before update: ' + nonSystemCase.Status);
        System.debug('nonSystemCase: '+ nonSystemCase.Id);        
        nonSystemCase.Status = 'Closed';

        update nonSystemCase;
        Case nonSystemCaseAfterUpdate = [SELECT Id, Status, OwnerId FROM Case WHERE OwnerId=:nonSystemUser2.Id AND Status = 'Closed' LIMIT 1];
        System.debug('Emails sent on nonSystemCase Closed: '+ Limits.getEmailInvocations());
        System.debug('Status of nonSystemCase after update: ' + nonSystemCaseAfterUpdate.Status);
        System.assert( Limits.getEmailInvocations()==2,'Non System should send 2 emails');
    }
    static testMethod void testEmailOnClosedCaseAlreadyClosed(){
        createContact('testFirstName', 'testLastName', HELPEMAIL);
        createCase('Case Closed Already Test', 'Closed', nonSystemUser.Id);

        Case alreadyClosedCase = [SELECT Id, Status, OwnerId FROM Case WHERE OwnerId=:nonSystemUser.Id AND Status = 'Closed' LIMIT 1];
        createEmailMessage('alreadyClosed@company.com', alreadyClosedCase.Id, 'Already Closed Test', 'Already Closed Body', HELPEMAIL);
        System.debug('Status of alreadyClosedCase before update: ' + alreadyClosedCase.Status);
        System.debug('alreadyClosedCase: '+ alreadyClosedCase.Id);        
        alreadyClosedCase.Status = 'Closed';

        update alreadyClosedCase;

        System.debug('Emails sent on already closed case: '+ Limits.getEmailInvocations());
        System.debug('Status of alreadyClosedCase after update: ' + alreadyClosedCase.Status);
        System.assert( Limits.getEmailInvocations()==0,'Already closed Cases should not send emails');
    }

    public static void createCase (String subject, String status, Id owner) {
        Case caseCreate = new Case(
            Subject = subject,
            Status = status,
            OwnerId = owner);
        insert caseCreate;
    }
    public static void createContact(String fName, String lName, String emailAddress){
        Contact contactCreate = new Contact(
            FirstName = fName,
            LastName = lName,
            email = emailAddress);
        insert contactCreate;
    }
    public static void createEmailMessage(String fromEmailAddress, Id parent, String isSubject, String body, String toAddress){
        EmailMessage caseEmailMessage = new EmailMessage(
            FromAddress = fromEmailAddress,
            ParentId = parent,
            Subject = isSubject,
            TextBody = body,
            ToAddress = toAddress);
        insert caseEmailMessage;
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are inserting only single record in your test method that is why you are getting single record, If you do that multiple time I am sure you will get multiple records but you need to remove LIMIT 1 from your SOQL.

One more thing which I want to point it out here is, every single test method runs in own context and Salesforce roll back data once test method execution complete so if TESTMETHOD1 insert two records count in TESTMETHOD2 will be zero if you will do SOQL in TESTMETHOD2.